# crawl a site with jsoup and make json in golang

Tags: json, go, web-crawler, jsoup, archlinux

I wanna crawl a site (bbs.archusers.ir) for making a new post or topic notification for users.

I try to write below code for a reading name, last change date, and URL every section and save into struct and save struct into JSON object. but link part in my struct won't get any value and either appear in the console for me, this is my code

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/anaskhan96/soup"
    "log"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Message struct {
    Name string
    Date string
    link string

}

type myJSON struct {
    Array []Message
}

var input []Message

func main() {

    resp, err := soup.Get("https://bbs.archusers.ir")

    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    doc := soup.HTMLParse(resp)
    links := doc.Find("div", "id", "brdmain").FindAll("a")
    for i := 0; i < len(links); i += 2 {
        link := Message{links[i].Text(), links[i+1].Text(), links[i].Attrs()["href"] }
        input = append(input, link)
    }


    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    jsondat := &myJSON{input}
    encjson, _ := json.Marshal(jsondat)
    fmt.Println(string(encjson))

}
```

which part I did wrong?

Comment: Like Mohammad.Naser says, you need to use upper case if your want to export a variable or function. Please consider taking a tour of Go, so you can get your fundamentals right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your Message struct
it must name 'link' with capital k ---< Link

```
type Message struct {
Name string
Date string
Link string
}
```

and output will be correct

{"Name":"مانجارو Manjaro","Date":"2018-10-18 10:55:09","Link":"viewforum.php?id=22"}